# Root URL in multilanguage Installation

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, url, multilingual

I have a multi-lingual joomla-installation(3.4) and I want to have a URL (within the logo) that linked to the respective root like *index.php/en*, *index.php/ru*, and so on.

This works pretty well in a local environment like xampp but when the installation goes live the URL in every language linked always to the german / standard version.

This is how I linked the logo.

```
 <a title="title" class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>"> </a>
```

In both cases Joomla is installed to a subfolder.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<a title="title" class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>"></a>
```

or

```
<a title="title" class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo JURI::base(); ?>"></a>
```

or

```
<a title="title" class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>"></a>
```

Comment: This works for me JRoute::_('index.php');